# How to do this in laravel using Laravel subquery with groupby and where

Tags: php, laravel, subquery, where-in

```sql
select * from `eplan_vacancy` where `reference_id` in 
    (select `eplan_ep_details`.`reference_id` 
        from `eplan_ep_details` 
        inner join `eplan_court_cases` on `eplan_ep_details`.`reference_id` = `eplan_court_cases`.`reference_id` 
        where `ep_cc_status` = 1 
        group by `eplan_court_cases`.`reference_id`) 
and `is_form_submitted` = 1 
and `st_code` in ('U05', 'S13', 'S01') 
group by `reference_id` 
order by `created_at` desc
```

Comment: You can always put a raw query in laravel if you don't mind or do you want this on Eloquent?

Comment: @Jovs yes i need Eloquent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use closure as the second parameter of the `whereIn` method.

```php
whereIn($column, $values, $boolean = 'and', $not = false)
```

```php
$return = DB::table('eplan_vacancy')
    ->whereIn('reference_id', function ($query) {
        return $query->select('eplan_ep_details.reference_id')
            ->from('eplan_ep_details')
            ->join('eplan_court_cases', 'eplan_ep_details.reference_id', '=', 'eplan_court_cases.reference_id')
            ->where('ep_cc_status', 1)
            ->groupBy('eplan_court_cases.reference_id');
    })
    ->where('is_form_submitted', 1)
    ->whereIn('st_code', ['U05', 'S13', 'S01'])
    ->groupBy('reference_id')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');

dd($return->toSql());
```

**Result**

```sql
select * from `eplan_vacancy` where `reference_id` in 
    (
        select `eplan_ep_details`.`reference_id` 
        from `eplan_ep_details` 
        inner join `eplan_court_cases` on `eplan_ep_details`.`reference_id` = `eplan_court_cases`.`reference_id` 
        where `ep_cc_status` = ? 
        group by `eplan_court_cases`.`reference_id`
    ) 
and `is_form_submitted` = ? 
and `st_code` in (?, ?, ?) 
group by `reference_id` 
order by `created_at` desc
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a full eloqent query that you can use to generate above query, Here i used Models that you need to change according to your model name.

EplanVacnacy: Model for table "eplan_vacancy"

```
$result = EplanVacnacy::whereIN('reference_id',function($q){
            $q->from('eplan_ep_details')
            ->select('eplan_ep_details.reference_id')
            ->innerJoin('eplan_court_cases','eplan_ep_details.reference_id','=','eplan_court_cases.reference_id')
            ->where('eplan_ep_details.ep_cc_status',1)
            ->groupBy('eplan_court_cases.reference_id')
            ->get();
            return $q;
        })
        ->where('is_form_submitted',1)
        ->whereIN('st_code',['U05', 'S13', 'S01'])
        ->groupBy('reference_id')
        ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
        ->get();
```